# How to get photo data in data collection CUBA Platform

Tags: cuba-platform

I have a data table in the frontend UI with first name and last name data and I need to add photos of these accounts. As I understand all the data should be in data collection, however, if you console log it, it doesn't show anything besides FN and LN. So, how do I get entity photo data and put it in the data collection?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing your code, but it looks like you haven't included the image attribute into the view. You can find a great guide on working with images in CUBA [here](https://www.jmix.io/cuba-platform/guides/working-with-images).